# A program keeps restarting when I close it (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows, restart

Relatively new to intermediate level Windows user here. I recently installed a game which kept restarting (automatically) every few seconds even after I closed it every few seconds. Windows (I use Windows 8.1) kept trying to open the .exe even after I uninstalled. I tried deleting a couple of registry entries of it (I guess I deleted a dll registry related to it)
[After deleting a couple of registry entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHfaz.png) 
but it still keeps trying to open it. What can I do about it?
[These guys keep coming up as I close them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixmb9.png)

Currently doing a CS course. This is my first question on stack overflow!

EDIT: This window keeps popping up every few seconds. (I have uninstalled it)[This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOatN.png). The game is Battlezone(1998) from Microsoft which itself is legit. I found it on a really old CD which I found in my house recently and I just installed it. It is clear on Avast Antivirus. Nothing suspicious there in Task Manager or in Startup

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Taskmanager to stop any process that is related to that programm.
If you have uninstalled it and the programm still starts it probably is still installed -> the .exe file hides somewhere.

Try find and delete it manually.
You can check if you have a system tray icon as well, some programms don't close if you close them but minimize into a system tray icon. These can often be closed using right click -> close.

Does the programm start automatically after pc start? -> check your autostart folder and the autostart tab of your taskmanager and remove it.

Anymore stuff you can provide us with? -> which game, screenshots, you sure it's not maleware?

Comment: Hi. Its not there in my task manager or startup. Its not sitting in my system tray either. Even when I have deleted it, Windows tries to open it again and again every few seconds( I'll put a screenshot of it).